# HTML5 navigator.geolocation within Trigger.IO

Tags: android, ios, html, trigger.io

I understand trigger.io has its own implementation of geolocation (forge.geolocation), but for various reasons I'd like to use the standard HTML5 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() call. Is this possible within a trigger.io app?

I've tried it and I'm seeing the following behavior across iPhone and Android:

== iPhone ==
User is prompted twice to allow location access. First by the native app, then by the underlying URL of the page.

== Android ==
The call to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() never returns unless you set a timeout on it in the options, in which case it just times out. User is never prompted to allow location access.

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone you will be prompted twice, this is one of the reasons Trigger provides a geolocation module.

On Android navigatior.geolocation should work, but you will need geolocation permissions for the app. If you enable the geolocation module (but still use navigator.geolocation) it should work fine.